# BERT Summarization for a column of texts

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, summarize

I'm trying to summarize 100 products descriptions from a dataset. To do so i simply tried to use summarizers

```
!pip install summarizers -q

from summarizers import Summarizers 

import pandas as pd
```

It worked pretty well for one sentence at a time.

```
textpanasonic="The NN-CS89L offers next-level cooking convenience. Its four distinct cooking methods - steaming, baking, grilling and microwaving ensure your meals are cooked or reheated to perfection. Its multi-function capabilities can be combined to save time without compromising taste, texture or nutritional value. It’s the all-in-one kitchen companion designed for people with a busy lifestyle."



summ(textpanasonic)

The NN-CS89L offers next-level cooking convenience.
```

but **do you know if it is possible to create a new column with a summary for each comment ?**

ValueError: text input must of type `str` (single example), `List[str]` (batch or single pretokenized example) or `List[List[str]]` (batch of pretokenized examples).

Thank you in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `apply` `summ` to the column with summaries. Since `summ` can take a list as input it will also process a pandas Series. To provide an example with multiple rows:

```
import pandas as pd
from summarizers import Summarizers
summ = Summarizers()

data = ["The NN-CS89L offers next-level cooking convenience. Its four distinct cooking methods - steaming, baking, grilling and microwaving ensure your meals are cooked or reheated to perfection. Its multi-function capabilities can be combined to save time without compromising taste, texture or nutritional value. It’s the all-in-one kitchen companion designed for people with a busy lifestyle.", "These slim and stylish bodies are packed with high performance. The attractive compact designs and energy-saving functions help Panasonic Blu-ray products consume as little power as possible. You can experience great movie quality with this ultra-fast booting DMP-BD89 Full HD Blu-ray disc player. After starting the player, the time it takes from launching the menu to playing a disc is much shorter than in conventional models. The BD89 also allows for smart home networking (DLNA) and provides access to video on demand, so that home entertainment is more intuitive, more comfortable, and lots more fun."]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['summaries'])
df['abstracts'] = df['summaries'].apply(summ)
```

|  | summaries | abstracts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | The NN-CS89L offers next-level cooking convenience. Its four distinct cooking methods - steaming, baking, grilling and microwaving ensure your meals are cooked or reheated to perfection. Its multi-function capabilities can be combined to save time without compromising taste, texture or nutritional value. It’s the all-in-one kitchen companion designed for people with a busy lifestyle. | The NN-CS89L offers next-level cooking convenience. |
| 1 | These slim and stylish bodies are packed with high performance. The attractive compact designs and energy-saving functions help Panasonic Blu-ray products consume as little power as possible. You can experience great movie quality with this ultra-fast booting DMP-BD89 Full HD Blu-ray disc player. After starting the player, the time it takes from launching the menu to playing a disc is much shorter than in conventional models. The BD89 also allows for smart home networking (DLNA) and provides access to video on demand, so that home entertainment is more intuitive, more comfortable, and lots more fun. | Panasonic DMP-BD89 Full HD Blu-ray disc player. |

Comment: Hi ! Thank you very much! Also i think i'm not great with pandas yet because i use an csv file and the result is summ(df2[['IDPTexteEn']])                                          
"ValueError: text input must of type `str` (single example), `List[str]` (batch or single pretokenized example) or `List[List[str]]` (batch of pretokenized examples)." (because IDPTexteEn is the column name of the comments and df2['IDPTexteEn'] = df2['IDPTexteEn'].astype('str')   doesn't change a thing ^^" )

Comment: You can't feed a dataframe to the function `summ`. As mentioned in my answer, try applying `summ` to a series (i.e. column): `df2['IDPTexteEn'].apply(summ)`.

Comment: Ah yes you are right! Thank you very much man T^T

Comment: Hiii 
Do you know if i can check the similarities of the two columns ? ^^"

Comment: Do you mean the similarity between summary and abstract? There are several modules, like [this one](https://pypi.org/project/sentence-similarity/) that do semantic similarity on sentence pairs. By the way, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yes! And ho sorry i tried to upvote it but couldn't but yeah i accepted your anwser !!! Thank you man you are a hero ! (now i will have to try to do a function for the dataset ^^)